# Extjs grid inside combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

guys. I need a tip about extjs.
I need to have a text field with ability to be filled from a grid. I mean that the user has a field with a dropdown, that he can open and select a grid row to bind to my text field. I will have a hidden field with an ID of the field to reference and some viewmodel based on the selected grid row to be showed in the text field. 
My question is how can i have some combobox with a grid (with livesearch actually, but it doesn't matter at the moment) inside it? Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may help: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132328-CLOSED-ComboBox-using-Grid-instead-of-BoundList